# Multidimension array iterating -- my eyes have crossed

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have this code:

```
    try {
                $this->_connect = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                $this->_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $stmt = $this->_connect->query('SHOW TABLES FROM '.DB_NAME, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                            $this->_schema[$value] = "";
                            }
                        }
                foreach ($this->_schema as $key => $value) {
                    $stmt = $this->_connect->query('SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH '.
                                       "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '$key'");
                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $this->_schema[$key][] = $row;
                        }
                    }
                foreach ($this->_schema as $key => $value) {
                    $colData = null;
                    foreach ($this->_schema[$key] as $keyTwo => $valueTwo) {
                        foreach ($this->_schema[$key][$keyTwo] as $keyThree => $valueThree) {
                            $colData[][$keyThree] = $valueThree;
                            }
                        }
                    $this->$key = new Table($colData);
                    }
                }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        if (isset($stmt))
            $stmt->closeCursor();
        }
    }

Class Table {

    public $select;
    public $update;
    public $delete;
    public $insert;
    public $replace;
    private $_columns;

    public function __construct($colData) {
        $this->select = new Select;
        $this->update = new Update;
        $this->delete = new Delete;
        $this->insert = new Insert;
        $this->replace = new Replace;
        $this->_columns = $colData;
        var_dump($this->_columns[0]);
        }
```

It's trying to grab the entire schema from a database.  The $this->_schema looks good when I var_dump it, so I think the problem is after it's done being made.  I'm trying to iterate over the database, grab each table's metadata and store that data in an array.  Then, I iterate over the array to create a new Table object for each table and send it an array of column data that I extracted.  I have been looking at this code for the better part of today and can't figure out where I went wrong.

When I var dump on the last line there, it dumps like this:

```
array(1) { ["COLUMN_NAME"]=> string(4) "type" } array(1) { ["COLUMN_NAME"]=> string(8) "username" } array(1) { ["COLUMN_NAME"]=> string(2) "id" }
```

Which is wrong -- it is the column names for table 1, column 1; table 2, column 1; and table 3, column 1.  It's supposed to be the name, data type, default, and max length of table 1, column 1.

Can anyone see where I went wrong or suggest a better method for going about this?

Comment: My eyes have crossed too...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it -- finally.  I took out the third foreach (unnecessary) and assigned the entire arrays under $keyTwo to $colData[$keyTwo] and it worked out how I planned.